# Why the search result return this?

Tags: cakephp

When I search the data by  find('all'), It get this resturn data:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => 
   Array ( 
     [0] => /* why this is not the model name? */
    Array ( 
      [id] => 1 
      [username] => ** 
      [password] => en 
      [memo] => **
    )
  )
)
```

How can I get the result like this?

```
Array ( 
 [0] => 
   Array ( 
     ['User'] => /* use the model name? */
    Array ( 
      [id] => 1 
      [username] => ** 
      [password] => en 
      [memo] => **
    )
  )
)
```

AND I find another question:

```
account table:
id username password
2  admin    123456

email table:
id title content      account_id
1  test  test email   2
```

Model like this:
    class Account extends AppModel {
        public $name = 'Account';
    }

```
class Email extends AppModel{
    public $name = 'Email';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Account' => array(
            'className' => 'Account',
            'foreignKey' => 'account_id'
        )
    );
}
```

So I code :

```
App::import('Model','Email');
$this->Email = new Email();
$result = $this->Email->find('all');
```

I get the result is :

```
Array ( 
 [0] => 
   Array ( 
     [0] =>
        Array ( 
          [id] => 1 
          [username] => admin 
          [password] => 123456 
          [title] => test
          [content] => test email
          [account_id] => 1
        )
  )
)
```

why the `Email` table's id covered the `Account` table's id  in the result??

And who can tell me which php expend do I need to install in my php??

Comment: What is `the data`...?

Comment: Why you need to know the model name? The query should be something like `Model_name.find('all')`

Comment: are you putting `App::import('Model','Email');
$this->Email = new Email();
$result = $this->Email->find('all');` in the Model? If so, and you are printing the result from the model, you are bypassing some pretty important constructor functions. You should not need the following lines at all... `App::import('Model','Email');
$this->Email = new Email();`. It should be $this->loadModel('Email'); $this->Email->find('all'); in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to instantiate models in your controllers. They will be lazily loaded when the code is run.

If you want to remove the numeric index and are just searching for a single record, you should use `find('first')` as this will return just one record, which will remove the numeric indexing from the result.

In your controller, UsersController for example, you should be able to do.

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {
  public function index() {
    $users = $this->User->find('all');
    var_dump($users);
  }
}
```

If you wanted to load a different model here, you could use `$this->loadModel()`

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {
  public function index() {
    $this->loadModel('People');
    $users = $this->People->find('all');
    var_dump($users);
  }
}
```

Comment: Which expand do I need to install in my php?

Comment: @Suebao Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.